# Lazy loading components in angular2

Tags: angular2-components

I am having three components that load simultaneously when angular app load. Is there any way that we can load component only when specific route navigate to.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the Angular 2 Router is all about. I strongly suggest you read the documentation on Router thoroughly.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

The steps you need to do are roughly the following:

1. Create a main component (ex: `my-app`) for your app with a `<router-outlet>` placeholder within its template.
2. Create your routes
3. Register those routes in your main application module
4. Add a reference to your main component (`<my-app></my-app>`) in your `index.html` file
5. Open up one of the URLs you registered as a route and the component you associated with that route will get created and inserted in place of your `<router-outlet>` element.

Comment: What if we don't want to use router to do the component-lazy-loading? Let say the module and one of the 3 components are eagerly loaded, how do we lazily load the other 2 components on-demand? I heard Angular 4 can handle this more straightforward, but I haven't really dig into this and it's still experimental.